# Do all Android devices allow debugging?

Tags: android

Probably my question is very stupid, but I can't find a clear answer.

For now, I'm developing and testing my apps on Nexus devices, so I have no problem with debugging.

I also want to buy cheap/weak phones and tablets to test, but I'm afraid to unfortunately buy a phone/tablet with debugging unavailable.

Since Android is very open, for manufacturers and carriers, is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any device that legitimately has the Play Store on it must be capable of serving as a development device.

Some manufacturers -- usually firms whose names you might not recognize -- will pirate the Play Store and therefore may not allow USB debugging mode.

So, if you stick with a major-manufacturer, Play Store-capable device, or another device that others have confirmed supports USB debugging mode, you should be safe.

Comment: The first sentence is not true, because i have my android device without play store, and is capable of debugging.

Comment: @Ivan: You have a logic error in your analysis. I said that a legitimate Play Store-equipped device must have debugging. I **did not say** that a device **lacking** the Play Store must **not** have debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Android's code is opensource, so people can do whatever they want.
But I don't think the any of the manufacturers or carriers would make the usb debugging option disabled.

Before buying an new phone or tablet, you can check for the full specifications to be sure.